# monitoring services, CPU, memory remotely on a Windows server machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, monitoring, memory, central-processing-unit, service

I'm looking for a tool that is able to (remotely) monitor CPU and Memory in a Windows server but most importantly, which service/process is using it.

Or-- is it possible to monitor a specific running service?

We got a server that freezes on regular basis and we're trying to find the culprit without using a local debugger.

Would be great if the monitoring software came with an agent that we can install on the remote clients for maximum accuracy.

Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at perfmon?

Comment: Or better yet, just browsed searched the site for [network monitoring](http://serverfault.com/search?q=network+monitoring) or browsed [monitoring tag](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/monitoring).

Comment: I do agree with tony roth below - performance monitoring, as important as it might be, will most likely not tell you why a server is freezing. Very few modern server OS will allow a single process to truly freeze the machine - you're probably dealing with hardware failure instead of resource exhaustion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [observium](http://www.observium.org/wiki/Main_Page) on a remote machine, then setup [SNMP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379100%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for windows on the machine you want to monitor and add it in your observium server. It will give you a lot of information. Another possibility is to setup a [nagios server](http://cloud101.eu/blog/2012/03/01/setting-up-nagios-on-debian-or-ubuntu/) with [nagiosgraph](http://cloud101.eu/blog/2012/03/01/extending-nagios-3-with-nagiosgraph-and-birdseye/) and install [nagioswin](http://www.nagios.org/news/77-news-announcements/273-introducing-nagwin-nagios-for-windows) as agent. You can also use nagios in combination with [WMI](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Windows/WMI).

Comment: why in the world would you need to set up SNMP and another server for monitoring just to read what wmi provides out of the box?

Comment: Well he asked for suggestions, so I gave a few, you can always share your own solutions.

Comment: Jim - Probably because using SNMP would also let him monitor almost anything else in his environment?

Comment: Plus, he needs another server because his request was for something that would work remotely.

Comment: perfmon works remotely.

Comment: had to down vote this answer its just non sensical in this case.

Comment: Actually it's not, it's a valid answer, as I point out what his options are to monitor a service. He wasn't asking for the best solution but a solution. I've used these tools to monitor a lot of machines, windows and linux. It works very well. Your argument is invalid.

Comment: So he has to go out of his way to create a solution which will cause him more issues then it will solve?  Most likely niether perfmon or observium will solve the problem anyway.

Comment: That's your opinion :)